# Python-Levenshtein Distance Error "Assertion failed!"

Tags: python, python-3.x, levenshtein-distance, cpython

I'm using Python 3.4.1 from Anaconda `'3.4.1 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)| (default, Sep 24 2014, 18:32:42) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]'` Windows 8 machine.

I installed the package with `pip install python-Levenshtein` all smooth no errors. (version 0.12.0)

But then I tried to use it:

```
import Levenshtein as lvn
print(lvn.ratio('a', 'A'))

# This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
# Please contact the application's support team for more information.
# Assertion failed!
# 
# Program: C:\Users\Me\Anaconda-P3.x-64b\python.exe
# File: Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c, Line 726
# 
# Expression: PyUnicode_Check(arg1)
# 
# Process finished with exit code 3
```

I tried `print(lvn.ratio.__doc__)` and it prints the docs just fine. 
What am I missing to make this work? Is this an issue with the specific version of Python I have, compiler bug, or a bug in the Levenshtein library

The Levenshtein module source code is available at [Github](https://github.com/ztane/python-Levenshtein/blob/c4d112c7147391a62b46403522057998157740f4/Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c#L726); the crashing line 726 being:

```
722 else if (PyObject_TypeCheck(arg1, &PyUnicode_Type)
723     && PyObject_TypeCheck(arg2, &PyUnicode_Type)) {
724   Py_UNICODE *string1, *string2;
725
726   len1 = PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(arg1);   // <-- assertion failure here
727   len2 = PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(arg2);
728   *lensum = len1 + len2;
729   string1 = PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE(arg1);
730   string2 = PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE(arg2);
```

---

I was able to reproduce this error on another Windows 8 machine with a fresh install of Python 3.4 (from Anaconda package - same package from my post)
Testing some other methods:
`distance()` - Exact same error.
`hamming()` - Same error but on line 805.
`jaro()` - Same error but on line 848.

---

I tried to install python-Levenshtein on Python 2.7 this time and I did get some warnings...

```
C:\Users\Thomaz\Anaconda32b\Scripts>pip.exe install python-Levenshtein
Collecting python-Levenshtein
  Using cached python-Levenshtein-0.12.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in c:\users
\thomaz\anaconda32b\lib\site-packages\setuptools-5.8-py2.7.egg (from python-Leve
nshtein)
Installing collected packages: python-Levenshtein
  Running setup.py install for python-Levenshtein
    building 'Levenshtein._levenshtein' extension
    C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Users\Thomaz\Anaconda32b\include -I
C:\Users\Thomaz\Anaconda32b\PC -c Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c -o build\temp.win32
-2.7\Release\levenshtein\_levenshtein.o
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c: In function 'levenshtein_common':
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:711:13: warning: pointer targets in assignment di
ffer in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
         string1 = PyString_AS_STRING(arg1);
                 ^
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:712:13: warning: pointer targets in assignment di
ffer in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
         string2 = PyString_AS_STRING(arg2);
                 ^
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c: In function 'hamming_py':
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:796:13: warning: pointer targets in assignment di
ffer in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
         string1 = PyString_AS_STRING(arg1);
                 ^
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:797:13: warning: pointer targets in assignment di
ffer in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
         string2 = PyString_AS_STRING(arg2);
                 ^
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c: In function 'jaro_py':
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:840:13: warning: pointer targets in assignment di
ffer in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
         string1 = PyString_AS_STRING(arg1);
                 ^
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:841:13: warning: pointer targets in assignment di
ffer in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
         string2 = PyString_AS_STRING(arg2);
                 ^
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c: In function 'jaro_winkler_py':
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:890:13: warning: pointer targets in assignment di
ffer in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
         string1 = PyString_AS_STRING(arg1);
                 ^
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:891:13: warning: pointer targets in assignment di
ffer in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
         string2 = PyString_AS_STRING(arg2);
                 ^
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c: In function 'median_common':
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:992:7: warning: pointer targets in passing argume
nt 1 of 'PyString_FromStringAndSize' differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
           result = PyString_FromStringAndSize(medstr, len);
           ^
    In file included from C:\Users\Thomaz\Anaconda32b\include/Python.h:94:0,
                     from Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:99:
    C:\Users\Thomaz\Anaconda32b\include/stringobject.h:62:24: note: expected 'co
nst char *' but argument is of type 'lev_byte *'
     PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyString_FromStringAndSize(const char *, Py_ssize_t)
;
                            ^
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c: In function 'median_improve_common':
    C:\Users\Thomaz\Anaconda32b\include/stringobject.h:91:32: warning: pointer t
argets in initialization differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
     #define PyString_AS_STRING(op) (((PyStringObject *)(op))->ob_sval)
                                    ^
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:1071:19: note: in expansion of macro 'PyString_AS
_STRING'
         lev_byte *s = PyString_AS_STRING(arg1);
                       ^
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:1077:7: warning: pointer targets in passing argum
ent 1 of 'PyString_FromStringAndSize' differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
           result = PyString_FromStringAndSize(medstr, len);
           ^
    In file included from C:\Users\Thomaz\Anaconda32b\include/Python.h:94:0,
                     from Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:99:
    C:\Users\Thomaz\Anaconda32b\include/stringobject.h:62:24: note: expected 'co
nst char *' but argument is of type 'lev_byte *'
     PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyString_FromStringAndSize(const char *, Py_ssize_t)
;
                            ^
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c: In function 'extract_stringlist':
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:1201:16: warning: pointer targets in assignment d
iffer in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
         strings[0] = PyString_AS_STRING(first);
                    ^
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:1213:18: warning: pointer targets in assignment d
iffer in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
           strings[i] = PyString_AS_STRING(item);
                      ^
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c: In function 'editops_py':
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:1650:13: warning: pointer targets in assignment d
iffer in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
         string1 = PyString_AS_STRING(arg1);
                 ^
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:1651:13: warning: pointer targets in assignment d
iffer in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
         string2 = PyString_AS_STRING(arg2);
                 ^
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c: In function 'opcodes_py':
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:1768:13: warning: pointer targets in assignment d
iffer in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
         string1 = PyString_AS_STRING(arg1);
                 ^
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:1769:13: warning: pointer targets in assignment d
iffer in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
         string2 = PyString_AS_STRING(arg2);
                 ^
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c: In function 'apply_edit_py':
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:1863:13: warning: pointer targets in assignment d
iffer in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
         string1 = PyString_AS_STRING(arg1);
                 ^
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:1864:13: warning: pointer targets in assignment d
iffer in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
         string2 = PyString_AS_STRING(arg2);
                 ^
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:1878:7: warning: pointer targets in passing argum
ent 1 of 'PyString_FromStringAndSize' differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
           result = PyString_FromStringAndSize(s, len);
           ^
    In file included from C:\Users\Thomaz\Anaconda32b\include/Python.h:94:0,
                     from Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:99:
    C:\Users\Thomaz\Anaconda32b\include/stringobject.h:62:24: note: expected 'co
nst char *' but argument is of type 'lev_byte *'
     PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyString_FromStringAndSize(const char *, Py_ssize_t)
;
                            ^
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:1894:7: warning: pointer targets in passing argum
ent 1 of 'PyString_FromStringAndSize' differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
           result = PyString_FromStringAndSize(s, len);
           ^
    In file included from C:\Users\Thomaz\Anaconda32b\include/Python.h:94:0,
                     from Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:99:
    C:\Users\Thomaz\Anaconda32b\include/stringobject.h:62:24: note: expected 'co
nst char *' but argument is of type 'lev_byte *'
     PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyString_FromStringAndSize(const char *, Py_ssize_t)
;
                            ^
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c: At top level:
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:6630:1: warning: 'lev_editops_total_cost' defined
 but not used [-Wunused-function]
     lev_editops_total_cost(size_t n,
     ^
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:6700:1: warning: 'lev_opcodes_total_cost' defined
 but not used [-Wunused-function]
     lev_opcodes_total_cost(size_t nb,
     ^
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:6655:1: warning: 'lev_editops_normalize' defined
but not used [-Wunused-function]
     lev_editops_normalize(size_t n,
     ^
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:2371:1: warning: 'lev_edit_distance_sod' defined
but not used [-Wunused-function]
     lev_edit_distance_sod(size_t len, const lev_byte *string,
     ^
    Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:2550:1: warning: 'lev_u_edit_distance_sod' define
d but not used [-Wunused-function]
     lev_u_edit_distance_sod(size_t len, const lev_wchar *string,
     ^
    C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -shared -s build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\levenshtein\_le
venshtein.o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\levenshtein\_levenshtein.def -LC:\Users
\Thomaz\Anaconda32b\libs -LC:\Users\Thomaz\Anaconda32b\PCbuild -lpython27 -lmsvc
r90 -o build\lib.win32-2.7\Levenshtein\_levenshtein.pyd
Successfully installed python-Levenshtein-0.12.0
```

Interesting... In Python 2.7, even with the warnings above, everything works.

---

I uninstalled the package then re-installed the one from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-levenshtein and now I can use python-Levenshtein just fine in python 3.4

Comment: You have not asked a question, and I do not see one that could be answered here.  Report this to the "application's support team" (author?, mail list?) as suggested.  There seems to be a bug in the C code.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy alas I am the "support team" :D

Comment: @Delicious was this ever resolved? I'm running into a similar error when running pre-commit for a project.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is just a partial one, I do not have Windows myself so I cannot debug the bug. However just looking at the source code leads to the conclusion that "this bug is impossibru" - possibly a compiler bug, or really nasty case of UB, or something.

There could be something wrong with how your extension gets compiled. Before [the line 726](https://github.com/ztane/python-Levenshtein/blob/master/Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c#L726), there are checks on lines 722 and 723 that explicitly check that the arguments are Unicode objects or subclasses thereof (if they are not, then the  entire `if` gets skipped and line 726 does not get run);

```
722 else if (PyObject_TypeCheck(arg1, &PyUnicode_Type)
723     && PyObject_TypeCheck(arg2, &PyUnicode_Type)) {
724   Py_UNICODE *string1, *string2;
725
726   len1 = PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(arg1);
727   len2 = PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(arg2);
728   *lensum = len1 + len2;
729   string1 = PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE(arg1);
730   string2 = PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE(arg2);
```

[`PyUnicode_GET_SIZE`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Include/unicodeobject.h#l399) has 2 assert statements, and both of them get inlined to line `726`:

```
#define PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(op)                       \
    (assert(PyUnicode_Check(op)),                    \
     (((PyASCIIObject *)(op))->wstr) ?               \
      PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) :                    \
      ((void)PyUnicode_AsUnicode((PyObject *)(op)),  \
       assert(((PyASCIIObject *)(op))->wstr),        \
       PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op)))
```

The first one asserts that the object indeed is an Unicode object or subclass thereof by checking the return value of [`PyUnicode_Check`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Include/unicodeobject.h#l382):

```
 #define PyUnicode_Check(op) \
             PyType_FastSubclass(Py_TYPE(op), Py_TPFLAGS_UNICODE_SUBCLASS)
```

The second one asserts that the `PyUnicode_AsUnicode(op)` sets the `wstr` member properly. The `PyUnicode_Check(arg1)` in your error output points to the fact that the first one fails here.

Now the funny part is that it shouldn't be possible to fail; the `PyObject_TypeCheck` succeeded, and it *is* a Unicode object (Python 3 `str`) so the assertion should also be a no-op.